# Need help with jQuery animate

Tags: jquery

Check out this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y7fEW/.

I'm trying to get the tan div on the left so that when you click it, it slides out, and when you click it again, it slides back in.

Currently when you click it, it slides out, but when you click it again, it slides out again. I followed a tutorial online to get this far, but I can't figure it out.

```
        $('#social').live('click', function() {
            var $lefty = $(this);
            $lefty.animate({
                marginLeft: parseInt($lefty.css('marginLeft'), 2) == 0 ? 
                $lefty.outerWidth() : 0
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `parseInt` function call:

use `parseInt("...")` instead of `parseInt("...", 2)`

```
$lefty.animate({
    marginLeft: parseInt($lefty.css('marginLeft')) == 0 ? 
                (40 - $lefty.outerWidth()) : 0
});
```

check: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/Y7fEW/6/

Comment: The second argument to `parseInt` is the base in which the number is supposed to be represented. With no base specified, JS will attempt to guess which base the number is in. This can present problems if the number is formatted (for example, `parseInt('012')` will evaluate to `10`, but `parseInt('012', 10)` will evaluate to `12`). It's always a good idea to specify the base, and generally speaking the base will be `10` unless something else is needed. So it's best to use `parseInt($lefty.css('marginLeft'), 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the slide effect from jQuery UI and just say

```
$lefty.toggle('slide');
```

Comment: I was not aware of the toggle effects that jquery ui has. Thanks for making me aware.